# Doctrine - Entity loaded without existing associations

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two entity types: `\Model\News` and `\Model\News\Category`.

**\Model\News:** (without couple of fields)

```
namespace Model;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="news")
 */
class News extends \Framework\Model {

    /**
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Model\User", inversedBy="news")
     */
    protected $author;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Model\News\Category", inversedBy="news")
     */
    protected $category;
}
```

**\Model\News\Category:**

```
namespace Model\News;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="news_category")
 */
class Category extends \Framework\Model {

    /**
     * @Id
     * @GeneratedValue
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=50, unique=TRUE)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="\Model\News", mappedBy="category")
     */
    protected $news;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->news = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
    }
}
```

Table data from \Model\News:

```
 id | category_id |  author_id
-------------------------------     ...
 4  |      1      |     NULL
```

Table data from \Model\News\Category:

```
 id |   name 
---------------
 1  | General 
---------------
 2  | Other
```

While I'm loading `News` type Entity with this particular code and doing dump with `\Kint` class:

```
$sId     = '4';
$sModel  = 'Model\News';
$oObject = $entity_manager->find($sModel, $sId);

d($oObject);
```

It returns me this:

[image: Image 1]

My question is, why `category` property from `$oObject` variable has `NULL` values despite the fact that the category with id = 1 exists in database?

---

**UPDATE:**

After above code, I want to load this category (with ID=1) separately. Same thing. But... when I'm loading a category with other ID (for example, 2) it's loading with no problems:

```
$oObject2 = $entity_manager->('\Model\News\Category', '2');
```

I have no idea what to do now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So... I finally came to solve the problem thanks to `@asm89` from `#doctrine` IRC chat in `freenode` server.

Doctrine is creating a proxy class which uses "lazy loading". Data is loaded only when one of getters is used.

So, after using `$oObject->getCategory()->getName()`, my category object available from `$oObject->getCategory()` was filled up with proper data.

Answer (score 3):

If you know that the category entity will be accessed almost each time you load news, you might want to eager load it (force doctrine to load it when News is loaded instead of when a Category property is called).

In order to do so, just add the `fetch="EAGER"` annotation on your association

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Model\News\Category", inversedBy="news", fetch="EAGER")
 */
protected $category;
```